# PostSharp on Mac

Tags: c#, postsharp

I want to use postSharp on Visual Studio for Mac. I downloaded postSharp package on Nuget.

But my onEntry Aspect didnt work ?

Is there any document about how to install postSharp macOS or how to build postSharp on visual studio for mac ?

Have a good day

Comment: PostSharp integrates with the build process (MSBuild) and not the IDE so there is nothing special about Visual Studio for Mac. Please be more detailed about your aspect, how it is used, and what do you mean by "it didn't work".

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
It is my problem and I solved it :)

Comment: @FatihAKSOY a nice thing to do would be to share how i solved your problem.